# Why message in DLQ of AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-sqs

Recently started using EB Worker.

Set lots of logging on a handler.

Every day there are +15 messages, but no exceptions were found.

I wonder why?

And if there any chance to put "reason" in an SQS DLQ by default?

A bit more about flow:
once a day I populate SQS with hundred of long-running tasks (5 mins each).

Maybe there are some default fallback solutions to put messages in DLQ after Xminx of being unreachable?

### worker config

- Inactivity timeout: 600 sec
- Retention period: 3600 sec

### main Queue config

- RetentionPeriod: 14 days

### Possibly same problem

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35507740/3337819

Nothing to do with the EB Worker configuration itself.

Comment: It sounds like some of the messages took longer than your 600 second inactivity timeout period to process.

Comment: And there should be no error, or at least - retry? Since I see that message only once

Comment: What do you mean by "and there should be no error"? The way you currently have the SQS queue configured, it will consider the message to have failed if it takes longer than 600 seconds, at which point it will move it directly to the DLQ. If you want it to wait longer, then increase that setting. If you want it to retry the message, then update the `maxReceiveCount` to a value greater than `1`.

Comment: I mean how would I know the error in the inability to process messages in 10 minutes? There should be no such problem. The question is "where to look to understand the root of a problem of why my DLQ is being populated while loggs are empty?"

Comment: After 3 minutes, no error +1 message in DLQ. 3 minutes is not 600 seconds. So the problem is somewhere else

Comment: The only reasons a message should be moved to the DLQ is if it isn't completed in the inactivity timeout period, or your EB worker returned an error code. If you are sure it isn't taking more than 600 seconds, then your code must be returning an error response occasionally, even if it isn't logging any errors.

Comment: told you it' not about my code. it's about nginx configuration of being unable to proceed for more than 60 secs. struggling to configure additional .conf. since worker tier ignores it for some reason